# SHA512 not working in vba for extended character set

Tags: vba, sha512

Hashing with SHA512 in vba using .net libraries is not correct if input string contains any characters > chr(127). Output is being compared to PHP SHA512. Any ideas?

I have tried different text encodings.

```
Public Function SHA512(sIn As String) As String

    Dim oT As Object, oSHA512 As Object
    Dim TextToHash() As Byte, bytes() As Byte

    Set oT = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
    Set oSHA512 = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Managed")

    TextToHash = oT.GetBytes_4(sIn)
    bytes = oSHA512.ComputeHash_2((TextToHash))

    SHA512 = ConvToHexString(bytes)

    Set oT = Nothing
    Set oSHA512 = Nothing

End Function
Private Function ConvToHexString(vIn As Variant) As Variant

On Error Resume Next

    Dim oD As Object
    Set oD = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
      With oD
        .loadXML "<root />"
        .documentElement.DataType = "bin.Hex"
        .documentElement.nodeTypedValue = vIn
      End With
    ConvToHexString = Replace(oD.documentElement.Text, vbLf, "")

    Set oD = Nothing

End Function
Private Sub Command0_Click()
    Dim strg As String
    strg = "abc" & Chr(148) & "defg"
    MsgBox SHA512(strg)
    MsgBox strg

End Sub

<?php
    $strg = "abc".chr(148)."defg";
   echo hash('sha512', $strg);
    echo "</br>".$strg;
?>
```

Comment: how does the incorrect hashing manifest? Can you show a worked example with comparison of outputs?

Comment: Using the following string "abc" & chr(148) & "defg" gives the following: 
php = 6c64101ac7f794e1af3b890630ecb052cf92cdb2d3abf5f8d134517ae1e0a59a9b71da247082e3139a5addbfc1380bb27aafe7d64632ec699795be13d34a7726   
vba = 9490f88b45e5195004fb6d458eb999d0dec1423138c2d5d0eeb515de0be8a06077ec6ba2f09140a152ff9a740d1b12bb837ca10566078ac5585ce28e632dcf9f
using string "abcdefg" both get same answer

Comment: I get yet another value when testing with https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha512.html

Comment: If I use online php hash I get same for [php](https://www.tools4noobs.com/online_php_functions/sha512/) and js but not same value as you post. What am I missing? If I run your php itself I get the value you mention so is this demonstrating your point or something about the algorithm used? I would have thought your script and php link would give same result.

Comment: Thanks QHarr. I pasted the string into that html and into the php (above) and all got the same answer as vba (above). So I conclude that something is happening when the string is sent in an xml via SOAP to the webserver that compares hashes.

Answer (score 0):

I have concluded that the SHA512 routines produce identical results. The problem is in how I am sending the data between vba and PHP.